# What is the path for MIT App Inventor to access a USB drive files connected via OTG?

Tags: app-inventor, usb-otg

I have a thumb drive with videos on it and it is connected to my Android using a USB OTG cable.  The File Manager app on my phone sees the USB storage device and I can click into it and see the folders and videos I need, but I cant figure out the correct path to load them from the USB device in app inventor.

I have tried this:
`file:///storage/usbdisk/MyCamera/RecentClips/front.mp4`

when the file is in a folder on the USB drive like this:
`d:/MyCamera/RecentClips/front.mp4`

but I get an error:

> Error 107: unable to load

How do I access files on a USB drive in MIT App Inventor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it is possible to access the files, but you could try the [file extension](https://puravidaapps.com/file.php) and its **AvailableStorageDirectories** method to find out the path

[image]